# What is the reason for the current spike in below simulation - at the end when cap voltage drops to zero?

Tags: power-supply, mosfet, circuit-analysis, ltspice, simulation

Is the current spike at the end due to the constant power behavioral model?

I have chosen an arbitrary MOSFET for the simulation. The initial current spike disappears when I add a series res to gate.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The voltage across the constant power load is dropping to zero, so the current could be expected to go to infinity at 0V.

To prevent the singularity (which tends to muck up convergence as well as being non-physical), there is a crossover in the simulation to a smooth transition to 0W at 0V, which by default begins to occur at +/-1V. at 1V your current will be 40A, which is exactly what you are seeing. The number can be modified by changing the *vprxover* parameter.

That's also why the V(HOLDUP) curve stops at 0V and does not go negative (or whatever you'd expect after reaching infinite amperes).